# Ejecutar función pasada como parámetro en Java

Tags: java, lambda

En el título de la pregunta he simplificado un poco mi problema para evitar malos entendidos.
Tengo una clase, con Thread como superclase, a la que paso como parámetro una función y se limita a ejecutar dicha función. Esta clase la utilizo para crear hilos, de forma que puedo ejecutar cualquier función en un hilo sin necesidad de crear una clase diferente.

```
public class ThreadEjecucionLambda extends Thread {
Runnable funcion;
public ThreadEjecucionLambda(Runnable funcion)
{
    this.funcion=funcion;
}
public void run()
{
    funcion.run();
}
}
```

Ahora bien, para crear varios hilos de un mismo método utilizo un bloque 'for', por ejemplo:

```
for(Ordenador ordenador : Persistencia.getListaOrdenadoresConSesion())
    {
        ThreadEjecucionLambda hilolambda=new ThreadEjecucionLambda(()->logica.EnciendeMonitor(ordenador.getNombrePC()));
        hilolambda.run();
    }
```

Lo que yo quiero conseguir es generalizar el for anterior de forma que pueda ejecutar un método, al que le pasaré como parámetros (Siguiendo el ejemplo) una lista de ordenadores y una función, y que en ese método se ejecute el 'for' y se cree un hilo para cada ordenador, de forma que a ese hilo le pasaré como parámetro la función anterior con el ordenador como parámetro de dicha función.
Lo que quiero conseguir es algo como esto (AVISO: ESTÁ MAL):

```
public void EjecutaHilosLambdaSegundo(ArrayList<Ordenador> listapcs,Runnable funcion)
{
    for(Ordenador ordenador : listapcs)
    {
        ThreadEjecucionLambda hilolambda=new ThreadEjecucionLambda(funcion(ordenador));
        hilolambda.run();
    }
}
```

Espero haberme explicado bien porque es un problema muy lioso de comprender.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: la pregunta se entiende. no entiendo pq estarias queriendo hacer eso...

Comment: esa parte que dices que esta mal, que error te marca?? otra pregunta es como quieres invocar esa parte que dices que esta mal??

Comment: Lo de porque quiero hacerlo está explicado en la pregunta.  El error que obtengo es que el método "función(ordenador)" no está definido. Es decir, toma la función pasada como parámetro como una función independiente.

Answer (score 1):

En java no puedes pasar funciones por parametro :(. Pero si lo puedes simular si estas utilizando java8 gracias a las lambdas de la siguiente forma y la interface Function.

```
Function<Clase Parametro entrada, Clase de resultado>

public void pasarFuncion (Object parametro, Function funcion){
... logica que se necesite...

resutadoFuncion = funcion.apply() :> esto ejecutara la funcion pasada por parametro.

}
```

Para poder pasarle esta funcion de forma facil.

```
pasarFuncion(parametro, ()->{
... Logica de la funcion que queremos ejecutar...
return "desde la funcion"
});
```

Si quieres puedes pesarle parametros de la siguiente forma

```
pasarFuncion(parametro, (String parametro1)->{
... Lógica de la función que queremos ejecutar...
return "desde la función"
});
```

Si quieres pasar 2 parámetros utiliza la interfaces BiFunction se utiliza de la misma forma pero te permitirá pesarla 2 parámetros a la función lambda.

```
(String parametro1, String parametro2) ->{
...Lógica de la función lambda.
};
```

Te dejo aquí mas información.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

PD: si quieres trabajar con hilos de forma asíncrona o sincrona te recomiendo que le mires RxJava ya que trabajar con Thread es un coñazo.
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Espero haberte ayudado.